# Rewrite in index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with rewriting hrefs in my website. First of all I managed to remove all .php extensions from na URLs, then I added rewriting all mydomain.com/img?id=X to mydomain.com/img/X, but I have been struggling with one more thing for some time and I would appreciate any help. My website consists of many pages and the link to page number X is mydomain.com/?page=X (e.g mydomain/?page=3), but I want to rewrite that URLs to mydomain.com/page/X

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
<something not important>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}//s%{HTTPS} ^www\.(.*)//((s)on|s.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%3://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9]+)/?$ img.php?id=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Right below this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}//s%{HTTPS} ^www\.(.*)//((s)on|s.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%3://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+\?page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It is not working properly. When I click a button to visit page 2 it redirects well and the URL is ok - mydomain.com/page/2. There are two problems:
When I go back to page 1 I get the following URL: mydomain.com/page/2?page=1. Second problem (not so important): when I move the cursor over the link to page 2 the old URL is displayed (with ?page=2)

Comment: Any ideas? Or maybe you know what this situation occurs

Comment: @user2593393 neither of those things have to do with the rules in the htaccess file. You need to change your content so that you use absolute URLs and URLs in the form of `/page/2`. The rewrite rules can't change the content of your pages.

Comment: Ok thats what I did. In 'a href's I typed absolute paths to my pages with a specific number and everything works fine. Thanks