# Rewrite page number in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with rewriting URLs in my website. I managed to remove all .php extensions from my URLs and addd rewriting all mydomain.com/img?id=X to mydomain.com/img/X, but I have been struggling with one more thing for some time and I would appreciate any help. My website consists of many pages and the link to page number X is mydomain.com/?page=X (e.g mydomain/?page=3), but I want to rewrite that URLs to mydomain.com/page/X

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
<nothing important>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}//s%{HTTPS} ^www\.(.*)//((s)on|s.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%3://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9]+)/?$ img.php?id=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite in index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503009/rewrite-in-index-php)

Answer (score 0):

This rule will rewrite /?page=X to /page/X

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /?page=$1
```

Comment: I added this line to the end of a file and it changed nothing. The URL is still mydomain.com/?page=2 when I go to page number 2

Comment: That is a different issue. To get the links on the page to point to a different URL you will need to change them in your code.

Comment: But I did the same thing with img. Instead of mydomain.com/img?id=X i get mydomain.com/img/X. What is the difference?

Comment: Apache doesn't modify page content. It will only handle the incoming urls. You can enter domain.com/page/1 and it will show page 1 but the links on the page will still point to domain.com/?page=1